# Can there be a margin added to the data explorer?

Tags: feature-request, design, data-explorer

I've done a few queries on SEDE, and I've noticed that it really needs left and right margins. The lack thereof makes it look rather ugly. Can these be added to the SEDE stylesheet?

Comment: Can you be more specific which part of Data Explorer you're referring to, maybe with an example?